# Why below code works when 2 conditions "==" but give empty list same code has 2 conditions "!="?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, conditional-statements, append

```
d1 = [{"name": "a", "author": "b", "read": False},
      {"name": "c", "author": "b", "read": False},
      {"name": "b", "author": "b", "read": False}]

temp = []

for i in range(len(d1)):
    if d1[i]['name'] != "a" and d1[i]['author'] != "b":
        temp.append(d1[i])

print(temp) # RESULT []
```

```
d1 = [{"name": "a", "author": "b", "read": False},
      {"name": "c", "author": "b", "read": False},
      {"name": "b", "author": "b", "read": False}]

temp = []

for i in range(len(d1)):
    if d1[i]['name'] == "a" and d1[i]['author'] == "b":
        temp.append(d1[i])

print(temp) # RESULT [{'name': 'a', 'author': 'b', 'read': False}]
```

In this case: if d1[i]['name'] != "a" and d1[i]['author'] != "b"
I expect it should append only those lists that doesn't match condition.

Comment: Is d1 the full array you're working with? As you have it now, there are no entries where d1[i]['author'] != "b", so nothing will ever get appended to your temp array.  I'd say both your codes are working exactly as they should given the example array you have.

Comment: Which language? Please include language tag in every non-generic question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have written the code gives the expected results.
You are naturally interpreting the code as it is written. So if name is NOT "a" AND author is NOT "b" then do the next step. Both logical statements need to be True to continue.. however because author is always "b" the condition will always be false.

Consider the following evaluation of Boolean operations and conditions

What you currently have

`>>> (not False) and (not True)`

`Result False` - The code block doesnt run

What I think you are expecting

`>>> not ( False and  True)`

`Result True`

Or written in the context of your code:

`if not ( d1[i]['name'] == "a" and d1[i]['author'] == "b" ) :`